# Which EC2 plan to choose?

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, sinatra

I wrote my first web app using Sinatra. It's pretty simple with a REST interface. I am running MySQL database and it connects to it using active record, very cool stuff. Also, I am running  another ruby program which basically queries the MySQL database every 30 seconds and does some work on the data and updates the db. 
Right now, I am running sinatra app on my laptop. I want to move this to a server because i can't keep my laptop on all the time.

I checked out Amazon EC2 and there's so many options that I am over whelmed. Is Amazon EC2 even a good choice? Is so, what option is best for me? I am not expecting any bandwidth.

Any pointers for someone starting with webservers/hosting would be great, Thanks!

Comment: If you're not sure, consider using Heroku. Its extremely easy to get started.

Answer (score 3):

Well there's a free micro instance for new customers so that seems like the logical place to start. If it's not enough you can consider upgrading, look at the reserved/on demand pricing and make an informed decision at that point.

Comment: Is micro instance kind of like heroku where I can only deploy the app and have no root access?

Comment: No, You have your own virtualized server instance with root.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at hosting with companies such as Heroku and AppFog?
They both offer free plans so you can give them a go before upgrading, or you may find the free plan is enough.